# Angular does not parse html-code characters when loaded dynamically

Tags: angular

I'm loading some records from an API that contains HTML that I want to list in my ionic / angular application.

The problem i have now is that the API return all special character in numerical HTML encoding.
e.g.: `&#39;` = `'` or `&#43;` = `+`

No matter if I do it with interpolation `{{html}}` or with `SaveHtml` (see below) it does not work.

```js
this.saveHtml= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.htmlString);
```

```html
<div [innerHTML]="saveHtml"></div>
```

That's how this string: `Autofill Service isn't shown` gets displayed:
[image]

It's also worth mentioning that if I insert this string as a hard-coded variable, it works, only the API response gets mixed up.

### Update

> Example

API call

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/59046327?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow
```

Returned title

```
module &#39;statsmodels.tsa.arima_model&#39; has no arguments &#39;seasonal&#39;, &#39;xreg&#39;, &#39;xtransf&#39;, &#39;transfer&#39; and &#39;include.mean&#39;
```

**That's how it looks like in my angular app** 
[image]
**And how it's supposed to look like**
[image]

Here is the corresponding [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046327/module-statsmodels-tsa-arima-model-has-no-arguments-seasonal-xreg-xtran) for this example.

Comment: `<div [innerHTML]="'&#39; '"></div>` also `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: First of all the meta tag is set by default and how does this div tag helps me?

Comment: This is a really weird problem because if angular isn't decoding uri-encoded characters properly, then your string should look like `%3Csmall%3EAutofill%20service%20isn%26%2339%3Bt%20shown%3C%2Fsmall%3E`. All your spaces including your html tags would also look like uri-encoded. I suspect your backend is also doing some kind of sanitization that cause this

Comment: I think this is because of sanitizing and therefore you need either to process your characters before processing template to the HTML or bypass HTML sanitizer (better to avoid when possible)

Comment: @NorbertBartko  can you please add sample html  data coming from the  backend here

Comment: My backend is the [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), where you can submit a request. But surely I will edit my question and add an example.

Comment: @NorbertBartko  has updated it , please check the same

Comment: Try to decode the data you receive with this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/he seems to be quite popular and therefore solid

Comment: I don't see any problem with your input https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwsyjt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing it as string should work doesn't matter if its dynamic or not, please see the working demo  where i retrieve the data from the same link provided in your question  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3mtt6b

**component.ts**

```
  htmlString = "module &#39;statsmodels.tsa.arima_model&#39; has no arguments &#39;seasonal&#39;, &#39;xreg&#39;, &#39;xtransf&#39;, &#39;transfer&#39; and &#39;include.mean&#39;";
```

**component.html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

Note : In your case most probably your html files or templates is not saved in correct encoding ( `utf-8`) if you are using `vs code` use `Save As > Save with Encoding...` to re save file in correct encoding .

Also you could  set the character set `utf-8` in your html file using the meta tag

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: @NorbertBartko my answer works, please see the updated answer

Comment: @NorbertBartko did you check it ?

Comment: Your _Note:_ was what caused the issues. I changed all files to `utf-8` and it works now.